# Converting VARCHAR to numeric in sql

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, criteria

Can anyone please help with converting String representation of value to int in sql.
For example I have 'FIVE' varchar filed in sql table, I need to convert it to 5 using sql queries.
At least is it possible to do so using just sql.

And is it possible to implement it in CriteriaAPI.

The main goal is to convert all string fields to numeric representation and find average value
per productId.

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_review")
public class ProductReview {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "prod_rev_seq")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "prod_id")
    private Product product;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Rating rating;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "prod_seq")
    @Column(name = "prod_id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    private Set<ProductReview> productReviews = new HashSet<>();

}

public enum Rating implements JsonDeserializableEnum {

ONE(BigDecimal.ONE, "Horrible", BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.valueOf(1.5)),
ONE_AND_HALF(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.5), "Poor", BigDecimal.valueOf(1.5), BigDecimal.valueOf(2)),
TWO(BigDecimal.valueOf(2), "Poor", BigDecimal.valueOf(2), BigDecimal.valueOf(2.5)),
TWO_AND_HALF(BigDecimal.valueOf(2.5), "Below average", BigDecimal.valueOf(2.5), BigDecimal.valueOf(3)),
THREE(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), "Average", BigDecimal.valueOf(3), BigDecimal.valueOf(3.5)),
THREE_AND_HALF(BigDecimal.valueOf(3.5), "Average", BigDecimal.valueOf(3.5), BigDecimal.valueOf(4)),
FOUR(BigDecimal.valueOf(4), "Good", BigDecimal.valueOf(4), BigDecimal.valueOf(4.5)),
FOUR_AND_HALF(BigDecimal.valueOf(4.5), "Very good", BigDecimal.valueOf(4.5), BigDecimal.valueOf(5)),
FIVE(BigDecimal.valueOf(5), "Excellent", BigDecimal.valueOf(5), BigDecimal.valueOf(5.5));

}
```

'FIVE' - 5

'THREE' - 3

etc

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your case you can just select product reviews with string representation of RATING and then for each do `Rating.valueOf()` to get matching enum entry and then get its numeric representation. All this things will happen in memory. Another way - create stored procedure on DB side, but it's not the best way. And if you have an option to change DB structure, maybe it's better to store rating as number? Hibernate provides nice feature called converters. `@Convert`, '@Converter', so you will be able to manage what is happening with enum entry on persist/retrieve

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Convert annotation to convert between java object field and sql field:

```
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 @Convert(converter = RatingConverter.class)
 private Rating rating;
```

```
@Component
@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class RatingConverter extends AbstractAttributeConverter<Rating, Integer> {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal convertToDatabaseColumn(Rating rating) {
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public Rating convertToEntityAttribute(Integer dbData) {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

You need to implement the above 2 method in `RatingConverter` to convert the fields based on your business logic.